# Differences between SoCal and NorCal real-estate

Tags: california, real-estate

I recall that there are some significant differences in real estate law or procedures between Northern California and Souther California.

What are the exact differences and where is the dividing line?

Additionally, it'd be interesting to know why there is such a separation of the state in the first place, where everyone to the north and south agrees to a certain mutually-exclusive set of procedures.

Comment: Do you have any reference for your belief that this is so?  I've never heard of such a thing.

Comment: @BrenBarn, I think I recall reading it in some kind of a book by Nolo about buying a house or some such..